# Simple worked-out example of computing future cashflows of other countries' assets?

Tags: macroeconomics, asset-pricing

I read through [a research note from Bridgewater](https://www.bridgewater.com/research-and-insights/our-2021-global-outlook) and a lot of the discussion centered on finding attractive cashflows of global stocks in USD terms. Here is a line for ease of reference:

> Across a number of countries, the combination of prior currency
> declines, equity declines, and rising interest rate differentials has
> made their discounted future cash flows in USD terms very cheap (i.e.,
> their unhedged assets). In the developed world, Japanese stocks
> unhedged in USD terms are as undervalued as we’ve seen in decades.

I would imagine it would be rather rigorous to set out to find exact data and unpack it step by step, so maybe we can just use fictional data: "Japanese Stock A" fictional interest rate at x%, ect. I'm merely interested in the logic.

### Question

Can someone provide a fictional worked out example that shows what 'computing future cashflows in USD terms' looks like? At least for me, the way the paper posed the idea in a very high level manner, it's a bit hard to follow.